# Placing a "!" before a condition statement

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

For example:

```
while (! ( (planet == "Mercury") || (planet == "Pluto") ) )
{
     <body>;
}
```

Would the above be the same as saying:

```
while ( (planet != "Mercury") || (planet != "Pluto") )
{
     <body>;
}
```

If not, what would it mean to place the NOT operation before the condition statement as shown in the first block of code?

Comment: `a is false OR b is false` is equivalent to `(a AND b) is false` (see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Look up DeMorgan's Theorem. It may be helpful. :)

Comment: For logic such as this, you might consider mapping the planet name to an enumeration value.  Then you could use a switch statement.

Comment: Oh, and `==` operator wont work for strings.

Comment: I think we're assuming here that the variable "planet" is a std::string, not just a char pointer or array.

Comment: @iharob `operator==` works fine for `std::string`s....

Comment: Whoops! You forgot to read your C++ book.....

Comment: Is that C or C++ code?

Comment: Also, Pluto isn't a planet :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help on clarifying this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent would be

```
while (planet != "Mercury" && planet != "Pluto")
```

This is a one of [De Morgan's laws in propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

[image]

Using C++ syntax, the above would be

```
!(P || Q) == (!P && !Q)
```

Comment: The planet being neither Mercury nor Pluto is the same thing as the planet not being Mercury and it not being Pluto.

Answer (score 1):

You should definetelly read on [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

TLDR outline:

```
!(A || B) = (!A && !B)

!(A && B) = (!A || !B)
```

This kind of logic is very basic and you will see and apply it a lot in computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

"`while (! ( (planet == "Mercury") || (planet == "Pluto") ) )`" mean if any one of these condition ....those  are`planet == "Mercury"` and  `planet == "Pluto")` ......is true  then "`(! ( (planet == "Mercury") || (planet == "Pluto") ) )`" will return false.

so

```
while (! ( (planet == "Mercury") || (planet == "Pluto") ) )
{
 <body>;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
while (planet != "Mercury" && planet != "Pluto")
{
 <body>;
}
```

And

```
while ( (planet != "Mercury") || (planet != "Pluto") )
{
 <body>;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
while ( !((planet == "Mercury") && (planet == "Pluto") ))
{
 <body>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of one of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). These laws tend to be very helpful for understanding how to correctly make these kinds of transformations (in my experience, it's a stunningly common thing to get wrong).